# Problem with scrollable

Tags: jquery, loops, autoscroll

I'm using this plugin - http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/plugins/index.html#autoscroll - and I want to make it looping.
At the documentation there is an option of "loop" but I can't enabled it together with the "autoscroll".

If you know this prob, please advise.

Comment: +1 Welcome to StackOverflow, Chaofix!

Comment: Have you tried `circular` chaining up with `autoscroll`?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `circular`:

```
$("#mydiv").scrollable().circular();
```

Comment: Ok I found my mistake... I used only the autoscroll() and I added the curcular().

Thanks

Comment: Today: $("#scroller").scrollable({circular: true}).autoscroll({ autoplay: false });